# Using jQuery that's loaded from a Chrome extension in Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension that ships jQuery and jquery is referenced from the manifest.json and works as expected when I reference to it from other JS files in my extension package.

However from Chrome console, even though I know my extension is loaded jQuery is not accessible

I tried accessing it like this:

`$('div').append();` etc. or 
`jQuery`

and neither of them works.

Not having console with jQuery support hinders the development process a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define your additional content script which would embed jQuery into every page.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Content script",
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*"],
        "js": ["jquery-loader.js"]
    }]
}
```

And inside `jquery-loader.js`:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'jquery.min.js';
(document.body || document.head).appendChild(script);
```

This way you would have jQuery on any page.

Comment: Thanks, this works when I do this: `script.src = chrome.extension.getURL('jquery.js');`

Comment: that js code works in the console as a way to load jQuery for debugging even if you aren't using jQuery on the page; specify the google CDN copy of jquery for example.